# New Line appearing when reading from input file, even though \n is Delimited

Tags: java, csv, io

Hello I have this code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("src/data/input.csv"));
input.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
    
    
System.out.println(input.next());
System.out.println(input.next());
System.out.println(input.next());
System.out.println(input.next());
System.out.println(input.next());
System.out.println(input.next());
System.out.println(input.next());
System.out.println(input.next());
System.out.println(input.next());
System.out.println(input.next());
```

Input.csv is:

> -149.95038,61.13712,"McDonalds-Anchorage,AK","3828 W Dimond Blvd, Anchorage,AK, (907) 248-0597"
>
> -149.93538,61.18167,"McDonalds-Anchorage,AK","4350 Spenard Rd, Anchorage,AK (907) 243-5122"

My expected output is:

> -149.95038
>
> 61.13712
>
> "McDonalds-Anchorage
>
> AK"
>
> "3828 W Dimond Blvd
>
> Anchorage
>
> AK
>
> (907) 248-0597"
>
> -149.93538
>
> 61.18167

**Instead I get:**

> -149.95038
>
> 61.13712
>
> "McDonalds-Anchorage
>
> AK"
>
> "3828 W Dimond Blvd
>
> Anchorage
>
> AK
>
> (907) 248-0597"
>
> *(blank line)*
>
> -149.93538
>
> 61.18167

I am not sure why the New Line isn't being skipped. Is there a better way to get values from an input file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a [Carriage Return/Line Feed issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations). On Windows (and a few other systems), the line delimiter is `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Replace

```
input.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
```

with

```
input.useDelimiter(",|\\n|\\r|(\\r\\n)");
```

This will make sure that Carriage Return (`\r`) is picked up.

However, the best way to read your file is to use a `BufferedReader` instead of a `Scanner` (you initialize it in the same way). Then, use `readLine()` to read your line and [`line.split(",")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split your line at commas.

Comment: This gave me no luck, unfortunately. I get the same result.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to take the first two tokens (the first two numbers) and store them as coordinates, and take the last 4 tokens of every line as one Address. Is there a better way to scan an input file? \\r as a delimiter doesn't seem to be working. Whats odd is I set up a while loop (The actual input file is thousands of lines long), and not every line has that mystery new line character at the end.

Comment: @Martin Get your program to print out the ASCII value of the mysterious newline.

Comment: @Martin See my newest edit for a better way to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

try using system line separator

```
input.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: This won't work because the OP is trying to use regex. You'd have to escape the line separator manually. Additionally, there's no guarantee that the `csv` the OP is reading was written on his OS. It's safer to just deal with `\r` and `\n` separately.

Comment: Using this Delimiter reads the entire lines as one input.next(), which helps with the fact it no longer picks up the new line character, but I still need to be able to read each individual token, Do you know how I would go about doing this. I tried 

input.useDelimiter(",|System.getProperty("line.separator")") which is wrong.